# How to build dynamic or shared library using LLVM compiler?

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I want to create shared or dynamic library by `LLVM` compiler that can be use like QAPIs. I am using `MDM9206` chip and `ThreadX RTOS`. I need to use this dynamic library with `DAM module`. But, it couldn't happen.
Please, let me know how to do this ?

Comment: ThreadX does not support dynamic/shared libraries, so you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: Yes, because All libraries are statically linked in ThreadX. All the libraries are part of single bin image. Tx code and QAPI core are compiled together to generate single image which is APPS image, this is part of apps_proc that configures interrupt/services/system call handling
DAM image is compiled with qapi libs which work using system call interface provided by TX + Qurt.

Comment: QAPI's are for DAM so QAPI library will get linked with DAM module which will use Qurt interface for handling system calls.

Comment: Suppose you have two DAM [i.e DAM 0 & DAM 1] and qapi libs [ i.e qapi1.lib, qapi2.lib]. You also have TX code and Qurt lib so when you build apps images then [tx lib and qurt libs] will generate image that is flashed on apps side

When you compile DAM suppose DAM0/1 then you need tolink both qapi1/2.lib.
When DAM need OS service then via QAPI & system call interface it will go to <QURT + TX handlers > but if they dont need OS service then QAPI will take care at library level.

Comment: Cons of static linking of QAPI with DAM:
If you have 2 DAM's [as mentioned earlier DAM0 & DAM1] both are build using same qapi libs so it means both DAM 0 & 1 image will have its copy of QAPI libs but in case of dynamic linking they will consume less memory.

Currently we dont have support for dynamic linking because it needs file system & memory management support.